# OCaml Ctypes - How to make the pointer to pointer

Tags: ocaml, ctypes, ffi

In C if you have a function like `int myfunc(struct mystruct **context)` then
the OCaml foreign signature will be

```ml
    type mystruct
    let mystruct : mystruct structure typ = structure "mystruct"

    let myfunc = foreign "myfunc" (ptr (ptr mystruct) @-> returning int)
```

The question is how to call the function? We can't take `addr (addr mystructinstance)`, so the code is wont compile:

```ml
    let inst = make mystruct in
    let res = myfunc (addr (addr inst))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The memory model of ctypes closely matches C, so the code you need to write will match what you'd write in C. You're right that `addr (addr mystructinstance)` is ill-typed, that is because it corresponds to `&(&mystructinstance)`, which does not mean anything in C.

In C, you'd probably write something like:

```
mystruct *p = NULL;
int err = myfunc(&p);
if (err == ok) {
  // p has now a usable value for the rest of the API
}
```

The equivalent code in ctypes will be

```
let p_addr = Ctypes.allocate (ptr mystruct) (from_voidp mystruct null) in
let err = myfunc p_addr in
(* check err *)
let p = !@ p_addr in
(* do things with p, typed mystruct structure ptr *)
```